# Swift-Alamofire request fails because of wrong parameter format in json and dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, alamofire, objectmapper

I have a model class which name is UserList and it has id, code, [Friends] as an array. In this case, Friends is a model class too. Friends class' attributes is name, surname, email, company, phone.

```
class Friends: NSObject,Codable,Mappable {

    var phone = String()
    var name = String()
    var surname = String()
    var company = String()
    var email = String()

    required init?(map: Map){

    }
    override init() {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
     name <- map["name"]
     email <- map["email"]
     company <- map["company"]
     surname <- map["surname"]
     phone <- map["phone"]
    }
}

class UserList: NSObject,Codable,Mappable {

    var friendsList = [Friends]()
    var code = Int()
    var id = String()

    required init?(map: Map){

    }
    override init() {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
      id <- map["id"]
      code <- map["code"]
      friendsList <- map["friendsList"]
    }
}
```

I fetch UserList class like this:

```
let contacts = UserList()

orderedContacts.forEach({
    for record in $0.value {
        let contact = Friends()
         contact.name = record.givenName
         contact.surname = record.familyName
         contact.email = (record.emailAddresses.first?.value as String?) ?? ""
         contact.company = record.organizationName
         contact.phone = (record.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue) ?? ""
         contacts.friendsList.append(contact)
    }
})

contacts.id = "57459bd9-f4c6-4fca-b5a4-6b4bc603b64c"
contacts.code = "BFF"
```

After all that, I have a JSON string which I converted it with SwiftyJSON.
This conversion gives me a correct json string. There is no problem. After that, I should convert this json string to a dictionary as Dictionary to pass it as parameter to Alamofire request.

```
let newJsonA  = contacts.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true)!
let newJson :Dictionary<String,Any>? = convertToDictionary(text: newJsonA)
```

When I send string to conversion, I see its printing on console like :

```
["Friends": <__NSArrayI 0x12aa96e00>(
{
    name = "First";
    email = "";
    company = "";
    surname = "Record";
    phone = "123456789";
},
{
    name = "Second";
    email = "";
    company = "";
    surname = "Record";
    phone = "987654321";
}
)
"code": "BFF", 
"id": "57459bd9-f4c6-4fca-b5a4-6b4bc603b64c" ]
```

As you see, json is not in correct format. After dictionary conversion, "<__NSArrayI 0x12aa96e00>(" is being added to dictionary. It causes Alamofire request fail like this.

```
Error Domain=com.alamofireobjectmapper.error Code=2 "ObjectMapper failed to serialize response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=ObjectMapper failed to serialize response.}
```

I'm sure I map response value correctly. I think the problem is json dictionary array which I send as parameter. Is there anyone who faced this issue?

Comment: You are encouraged to drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of `Codable`. It's faster, easier to use and built-in.

Comment: You are using at some point the description of the object. When you do `contacts.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true)!` you need to tell that it needs to do jsonify also friends. That's why. Question is, why not use Codable instead of ObjectMapper & SwiftyJSON?

Comment: @vadian and Larme, thanks a lot to you for answers. I completely focused on wrong point. It had caused that one of Friends' phone field was empty. Phone number field was not nullable on database. When I checked all records, I saw one of them is empty. I solved problem and I got response from server. I'm curious why you suggest Codable instead of ObjectMapper. Is it more effective than? If it so, I can change it. Actually, I didn't research too much about their differences. I'm waiting your helps.

Comment: Codable is "native" in Swift 4+. ObjectMapper is a third party lib.